# How to convert datetime string of different formats in a valid datetime in SQL 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, date-format

I have a table in SQL database in which there is an NVARCHAR(MAX) column. In it, the data is stored as 'Datetime1&Datetime2&Datetime3&Datetime4...'(& separated dates. I know this is not correct way to store data but I have to support an older system).

Now the issue is that this table is used in multiple sites and hence the data coming in this column could come in different formats. Means, for one site, the datetime could be in the format '22-06-2015 13:00:00' and for some other site, the datetime could be in the format '2015-06-22 13:00:00' or '2015-22-06 13:00:00'.

I have to break the data from this column and store individually each value  as a datetime in a new row in another table. This has to be datetime only as I need to do some date operations like comparison, Datediff, Dateadd etc.

So, in my Stored Procedure, if I select value as `convert(datetime,[date],121)`, then it gives error if the string is in any other format than 121(yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.mmm).

So how can I address this problem that this datetime string could be converted to actual datetime without any issue of a particular format or system format?

Comment: Assuming that you have dates in the string like represented below, How will you differentiate between month and a date? 





'2015-01-01 13:00:00 $ 2015-02-01 13:00:00'

Comment: @tharunbandarupalli That is managed in the front end code, I just need to save all the values as a valid datetime value.

Comment: Sql server is allowing 

(SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'))

this format of date string to be converted to DATETIME. So Using string manipulations try to build date string of the above format for successful conversion.

Comment: @tharunbandarupalli Thanks for the reply. I was also thinking of custom string manipulation, but the variations of date formats are so much that it may be difficult to cover all of them.